# Replace same multiple chars with one char

Tags: c#, regex

How can i replace multiple chars with one desired char using regex?

Example : "----" to be "-" , "////" to be "/" and so on .

Comment: You should separate questions and answers. So answer your own question as soon as possible. [Etiquette for answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

Comment: Also `\x2D` seems overkill when `\-` will do - `@"[\-]{2,}"`

Comment: while(indexOf2Char != -1) replace char - You don't need regex

Comment: I don't really know how things works . I find the Answer your own question button . Thanks you for helping .

Comment: Why it is necessary to use regular expression here?
It can be done by other things as well

Comment: I use regular expression because i don't really search for performance and if i parse my string with a loop i must look after 2 chars at every step because i replace "-" with "-" ( same char -> so i must look after sequences ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(-){2,}");
string s = reg.Replace("-----regex----is---cool", "$1");//=> -regex-is-cool
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentUrl =  currentUrl.Trim() ; 
    currentUrl = Regex.Replace(currentUrl, @"[/\x2D/]{2,}", "-");
```

where 2D is the hexa for "-" char .

Here i replace two or more "-" with one "-" .

You can do this for every pattern .

Convert in hexa here : http://www.string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx